# Cannot subscript a value of type '[ClassName.StructName]' with an index of type 'ClassName.StructName'

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I ran into this problem and haven't found any solution yet.

Struct

```
struct hourSlot{
        lazy var timeWorkingString = "\(startTimeStructString) -  \(endTimeStructString)"
        var startTimeStructString = "null"
        var endTimeStructString:String = "null"
        (Some logic here)
}
```

Problem here:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[WorkTimeModifer.hourSlot]' with an
>   index of type 'WorkTimeModifer.hourSlot'

```
var hoursArray = [hourSlot]()
func updateTable(){
        for index in hoursArray{
            let timeFinal:String = hoursArray[index].timeWorkingString
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are dealing with fast enumeration loop, which means that `index` the current object itself not the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Int` type when you subscript an array not index here it's of type `hourSlot`

```
for item in hoursArray {
    let timeFinal = item.timeWorkingString
}
```

OR

```
for (index,item) in hoursArray.enumerated() {
    let timeFinal = hoursArray[index].timeWorkingString
}
```